# What is the LayoutInflater in Android? How does it differs from findViewById?

Tags: android, layout, layout-inflater, android-inflate, findviewbyid

An example `LayoutInflater` code:

```java
View inflate = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.,parent,false);
```

Can't understand the work of `LayoutInflater` in Android. Tried to read the official documentation of the android but, couldn't get the concept.

Comment: Layout inflater is responsible for parsing XML layout resources and producing view hierarchy made out of Java objects that you can then bind and manipulate in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main difference between findViewById and LayoutInflater is that findViewById is used to access existing views in a layout, while LayoutInflater is used to create a new view hierarchy from an XML layout file.

FindViewById is a method of the Activity class, while LayoutInflater is a separate class on it's own.

FindViewById is used to access a view in the current layout, this means lets us find Views from layouts written in XML and returns a reference to their Java objects, while LayoutInflater is used to create a new view hierarchy from an XML layout file, so this class is the responsible for “inflating” the layouts.

Hope it helps.